¿Cómo consumir un servicio WCF con credenciales en c#?
Tengo esto configurado en mi app.config
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="IntegratorPortSoap11">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://e-ws.factura-core.com/integrator/ws"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IntegratorPortSoap11"
            contract="WsNeogrid.IntegratorPort" name="IntegratorPortSoap11" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>  

Y en mi clase para ejecutar algún método enviando las credenciales es esta, las credenciales me piden en el header
        try
        {
            var client = new IntegratorPortClient();

            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "123456";

            sendMessageRequest body = new sendMessageRequest
            {
                in0 = "NGA232",
                in1 = "09",
                in2 = "TXT"
            };

            var response = client.sendMessage(body);

            Console.WriteLine("Respuesta recibida");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }

Y me retorna el siguiente error

Ya he realizado varias pruebas y no encuentro alguna solución, espero me puedan ayudar.
